# iOS referencing a specific dictionary based upon view controller title

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a few different NSDictionary data sets that I need to access depending on the title of the current view controller. For instance, if the current title is Title One, I need to access the NSDictionary named titleOneData.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

**Existing hard coded dictionary selection:**

```
tempMarker = [titleOneData valueForKeyPath:[element stringByAppendingString:@".Marker Path"]];
```

I need to be able to change "titleOneData" in that line to be "titleTwoData" if the title value of the current view controller is "Title Two".

Comment: Show us what you are trying.

Comment: Please provide more data. Accessing the title is simple as viewControllerInstance.title, and comparing it using isEqualToString: is no problem.
We need more context to answer this question properly.
For now i can only tell you that the good idea would be too keep your dictionaries in a dictionary xD and set view controller titles as keys, that should give you easy access :)

Comment: Is the code inside view controller instance whose title you need to check?

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir Yes the code is currently inside the view controller instance.

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir The dictionary of dictionaries seems to be a possible way to go about this. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Ok, solved with: 
`NSString *currentTourDataFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.title stringByAppendingString:@" Data"] ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *currentTourData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:currentTourDataFilePath];`

Comment: I'm basically just generating the NSDictionary from the plist file that holds the data that corresponds to the view controller's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Dobroćudni Tapir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054786/dobrocudni-tapir), store your *dictionaries* namely **titleOneData**, **titleTwoData** etc. in another *dictionary* say **titles**, with keys "**titleOneData**", "**titleTwoData**" etc.

Then access the respective *dictionary* using the `view controller`'s *title* as follows:

```
NSDictionary *currentDictionary = [title valueForKey:self.title];
tempMarker = [currentDictionary valueForKeyPath:[element stringByAppendingString:@".Marker Path"]];
```

Hope this helps!